# Angular 7: Unable to get the value from service which is shared between components

Tags: angular

I have a Service class with setter and getter

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    name: string;

    getName(): string {
       return this.name
    }

    setName(newname: string) {
        this.name = newname;
    }

}
```

I also defined this in app.module

```
providers: [ DataService ]
```

And set a name in one component and try to retrieve from another. I get undefined.

Comment: Are you adding the service to the providers array of any other module or either of your components?

Comment: Yes, I do set value in a ngInit of one component and try to retrieve in another component

Comment: No. this service is injected via the constructors of component

Comment: Could you provide the example in a stackblitz so we can take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Your component is likely calling `getName` before anything has had a chance to call `setName`. You're probably doing this in `ngOnInit`. I would recommend you try this Subject-Observable pattern instead (don't forget to import whatever you need from rxjs):

service.ts

```
name: string; // not always necessary/desired
nameSub: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(''); // initializing with empty string--could be anything you want
getName: Observable<string> = this.nameSub.asObservable();

setName (name: string) {
  this.name = name; // not always necessary/desired
  this.nameSub.next(name);
}
```

any-component.ts

```
myName: string;
sub: Subscription;

ngOnInit () {
  this.sub = dataService.getName.subscribe(name => {
    // assign name to local variable or class property, for example:
    this.myName = name;
  });
}

inputHandler (event) {
  // calling this method will automatically update `myName` through the subscription in ngOnInit!
  dataService.setName(event.name);
}

// Don't forget to unsubscribe when you create your own subscriptions
ngOnDestroy () {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

This pattern allows you to keep the state in one place (the service), but also be notified anywhere else the moment anything changes by leveraging RxJs Observables.

You can read about BehaviorSubjects and the rest here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject